# How to add a "select path" input in a UI addon script?

Tags: scripting, python

I have to allow users of my addon to select a path via the directory browser window of blender.

The path is already set in an external ".conf" file, but I need it to be customizable via blender GUI, to avoid users to edit the config file manually.

I tried many things, (note that I'm a novice with the blender API), for example :

```
#(...)
bpy.ops.buttons.directory_browse()
# or
col = layout.column()
col.operator("file.directory")
# or
col.operator("buttons.directory_browse")
# or
col.prop(path, 'choose a folder')
#(...)
```

But nothing works. And can't find a way to do this after a day of seeking.

What I want to achieve is something like this :
[image]
Note that the input could be pre-filled with the config file's default value.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I'm completely new to all this.
I wanted to know if theres a way of storing a path enter by the user in the select path box into a variable PATHVar in order to use it later.. bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx( filepath=PATHVar + name + ".fbx") I know that I should be using the solution mentioned by Polosson but conf_path would simply batch export to the blender directory and not a custom one.
I only ask here because it seems not to be much information around addon development really. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution:

First, I had to define a custom property in the `register()` function:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.conf_path = bpy.props.StringProperty \
      (
      name = "Root Path",
      default = "",
      description = "Define the root path of the project",
      subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
      )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.conf_path
```

Then in the `draw()` method of the panel class, I had to call the property this way:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column()
    col.prop(context.scene, 'conf_path')
```

And... **it worked**!

Now, I wanted to display the default value (which is stored in a separate ".conf" file), in the "file input" when Blender starts (or the add-on is enabled).
To do so, I just had to call a function which get this value, and put it in the "default" parameter of the property definition:

```
def register():
    default_path = get_path_from_config_file()
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.conf_path = bpy.props.StringProperty \
      (
      name = "Root Path",
      default = default_path,
      description = "Define the root path of the project",
      subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
      )
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `layout.template_image` command:

> ```
> template_image(data, property, image_user, compact=False)
> ```
>
> Item(s). User interface for selecting images and their source paths
>
> Parameters:
>
> - **data** ([`AnyType`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_0/bpy.types.AnyType.html#bpy.types.AnyType), (never None)) – Data from which to take property
> - **property** (*string*) – Identifier of property in data
> - **compact** (*boolean*, *(optional)*) – Use more compact layout

Here's a link to the [relevant documentation for `bpy.types.UILayout`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_0/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_image).

Comment: Well, I tried this too, but can't get it to work. Anyway, in my script the path won't be used for images. However, I think I finally found a solution, so I'll answer my own question. Thanks !