# Use Blender's file browser via python, without a UI panel

Tags: python, file-browser

I am trying to run a script that prompts the user for a desired directory and file name for export. Ideally, this script would be run from the *File -> Export* menu and pop up a file browser window similar to how the included export scripts function.

The only way I've found to call Blender's file browser is via a file path property for a UI panel (i.e. [How to add a "select path" input in a UI addon script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/how-to-add-a-select-path-input-in-a-ui-addon-script)). Is what I'm trying for possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender comes with a template for this, see:

*Text Editor -> Templates -> Python -> File Export*

Run the script, it will execute immediately (which is just for testing), but it also adds a menu item to the export menu.