# Way to browse all type of files by operator button class in panel

Tags: python

I want to search a file on pc by pressing a button , 
The button will be drawn in the ui panel with:

```
class MYBROWSERBUTTON_OT_Seach(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "my.browser"
    bl_label = "Search file"

    def execute(self,context):
        ###In this operator I would like to open a file search popup, and assign the path to file_finder(StringProperty)

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

class MAT_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):

```
bl_label = "My Panel"
bl_idname = "My Idname"
bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
bl_region_type = "UI"


def draw(self, context):
    row.operator("my.browser", text='Search file')
```

register string:

```
class MyProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    file_finder: StringProperty()
```

register property

```
Scene.my_setting= bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProp)
```

I would like to have the full path name with file name, saved in the StringProperty ---> c:mydyr/my_folder_/my_file.###

I'd like to do it that way, but I don't know very well and I don't know if it's a correct way

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2386/935) help?

Comment: @sambler is usefull, but this method give me only path folder , not path + file name